# Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized for jar from remote

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, jcenter

In the logs:

```
Could not get resource 'https://<locally hosted artifactory>/<virtual repo>/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.2.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.2.13.RELEASE.jar'.
```

`<virtual repo>` is a group that, amongst others, contains: https://jcenter.bintray.com and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

i do find, in Artifactory UI, the pom of the requested jar
`jcenter-cache/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.2.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.2.13.RELEASE.pom`

also, there is a permission on the virtual repo that grants to my user rights: READ, Deploy/Cache
when i look into the effective permissions of the pom, in Artifactory UI, my user is there with the mentioned rights

i try to download dependencies with Gradle as the build system for my project, and it is configured with the virtual repo

```
    repositories {
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryUrl}/<virtual repo>"
        credentials {
            username "${artifactoryUser}"
            password "${artifactoryApiKey}"
        }
    }
}
```

this is configured both in `settings.gradle` under `pluginManagement` and also in root of `build.gradle`
(anyway, i think the credentials part works); something else is broken.

**the permission in place used to work 2 days before: 2021-05-26 (at some point, it just stoped working)**

does this have anything to do with https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/  ?

what should i try to debug this? are there any logs where i can see the request being denied (i do have admin access to Artifactory, but i cannot find anything so far in the logs under `System Logs Viewer`)